# Angular 4 submit form errors

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

I have several problems with my form. It has been designed to be a search tool. 1 input, 1 button and here we go. But something is not right. I use an API, when you send a string to it, it brings you back all values that contains in particular string. When you send an empty value, it returns all possible values.

The main problem is on submitting the form. Depending on code I'm getting:

1. Cannot read property 'value' of undefined;
2. _this.form.get is not a function.

Here's the code:

**Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class FleetService {
  private defUrl = 'some.url';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getFleet(fleetname?: string) {
    const url = (!fleetname) ? this.defUrl : 'some.url=' + fleetname;
    return this.http.get(url)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
export class FleetComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchQuery = new FormGroup({
      fleetname: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
  }

  public flota: FleetHead[];
  public searchQuery: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fleetService: FleetService, private router: Router) {
    this.fleetService.getFleet().subscribe(fleet => {
      this.flota = fleet;
    })
  }

  search(searchQuery) {
    this.fleetService
      .getFleet(searchQuery.value.fleetname)
      .subscribe(searchQuery => {
        this.searchQuery = searchQuery;
        this.router.navigate(['/fleet']);
      })
  }

}

interface FleetHead {
  fleets: FleetInfo[];
}

interface FleetInfo {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

**Template**

```
<form class="form-inline" novalidate (ngSubmit)="search(fleetname)" [formGroup]="searchQuery">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" formControlName="fleetname" type="text" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

<div *ngIf="flota">
  <p-dataTable [value]="flota.fleets">
    <p-header>Search results</p-header>
    <p-column field="id" header="ID" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="name" header="Name" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
  </p-dataTable>
</div>
```

When I use that template it returns `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`, when I add a `#fleetname` to input it returns: `_this.form.get is not a function`.

This template is operated on route `/fleet` and on submit I want to stay on that page, but with updated values so the search result may be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting the error

> cannot read property 'value' of undefined

is because you are passing the incorrect value in your submit, it should be:

```
(ngSubmit)="search(searchQuery)"
```

to be able do this in your function:

```
this.fleetService
  .getFleet(searchQuery.value.fleetname)
     .subscribe(...)
```

You should also not need to use router navigate here, so remove this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/fleet']);
```

the values should get updated after doing your search :) From what I am seeing you do not want to save the values to the variable `searchQuery`, but to the variable `flota` that shows the result, so shouldn't your function look like this:

```
search(searchQuery) {
  this.fleetService
    .getFleet(searchQuery.value.fleetname)
    .subscribe(searchQuery => {
      this.flota = searchQuery;
    })
}
```

Here is a

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/bWIdRwsrrMWPFJmyppIC?p=preview)

with the same setup, but we are instead using omdbapi :)

Comment: Works as intended. Thank you, again :)

Comment: Glad to hear! You are very welcome, again :D Have a great day! :)